# iptables time rule does not work in reverse time

Tags: linux, iptables

I have this rule to control my macs addresses and work fine:

Note: $mac is a variable that contains the macs addresses of my local network, so iptables rule goes inside a "for; do done"

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source $mac -p tcp --dport 80 -m time --timestart 08:00:00 --timestop 18:00:00 --weekdays Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j ACCEPT
```

However, the rule stops working, if I change the schedule in reverse. That is, it starts at 6:00 PM and ends at 8:00 AM the next day

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source $mac -p tcp --dport 80 -m time --timestart 18:00:00 --timestop 08:00:00 --weekdays Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j ACCEPT
```

Why does this happen?. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use 2 iptables rules like those:

```
iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source $mac -p tcp --dport 80 -m time --timestart 18:00:00 --timestop 23:59:59 --weekdays Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j ACCEPT

iptables -A INPUT -s 192.168.1.0/24 -i eth1 -m mac --mac-source $mac -p tcp --dport 80 -m time --timestart 00:00:00 --timestop 08:00:00 --weekdays Mon,Tue,Wed,Thu,Fri -j ACCEPT
```

Comment: When we set --timestart or --timestop, iptable uses only time in format HH:MM:SS without date YYYY-MM-DD. It does not count next day. And on my opinion, if this rule could work, it would difficult manage it.